# How to pass argument to an environment in command form

Tags: environments, enumerate, arguments

I have defined

```
\newenvironment{cvolist}[1][2.25cm]{\setlength{\pwd {#1}\enumerate} 
{\endenumerate \aftergroup\ignorespacesafterend\vspace{-1.5em}}
```

That way I can have a list in an environment (this may sound complicated and it is but it is part of a bigger project that I do not control, so do not argue with the complication, please).

What I would really like to write is

```
\newenvironmenth{cvolist}[1][2.25cm]{\setlength{\pwd}{#1}\enumerate[leftmargin=2cm]}
{\endenumerate \aftergroup\ignorespacesafterend\vspace{-1.5em}}
```

so that I can actually choose the left margin for the items. However, this gives an error when I call the \item (without the argument for enumerate I get no error).

Any idea on how I can pass an argument in command form?

I write in command form because I have read that nested environments give errors.

Comment: `\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=2cm}` before calling `\enumerate`?

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician, but I am afraid what that does is printing `[enumerate]leftmargin=2cm` just before the list starts.

Comment: Are you doing `\usepackage{enumitem}`? Where did you learn `\aftergroup\ignorespacesafterend`?

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a compilable example rather than this snippet. Then we could test real suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @egreg I was missing calling enumitem package. Now Texnician's solution works.
As for the \aftergroup stuff, I am really modifying an old cls file which was given to us at an old job to format our CVs consistenly.

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia `\ignorespacesafterend` does `\global\let\if@ignore\iftrue`, so doing it after the current group has the only effect of not issuing it at the proper time.

Comment: @TeXnician I actually tried but I seemed to run into more problems because it is part of a larger project which is hard to excise now. However, once I did `\usepackage{enumitem}` your solution works. Thank you.

Comment: @egreg Mmmh, I am not sure what you mean, but it displays what I need, so I think I will leave it as is not to risk touching something else. The original environment seems to be used in many places and it contains that. Thank you for yor help.